# Extract matched dataset

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I need to perform propensity score in order to match patients from 2 groups (example: treatment A and treatment B). I usually do it with "MatchIt" package which allow me to extract matched dataset through the function "match.data".
Now, I need to perform propensity score in order to match patients from more than 2 groups (example: treatment A, treatment B and treatment C). I performed it through "twang" package, but I'm not able to extract the matched dataset (what "match.data" does in "MatchIt" package).
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`twang` doesn't do propensity score matching. It does propensity score weighting (that's what the W in TWANG stands for). No units are dropped, and each unit receives a weight estimated by `mnps()`. You can use that weight in a survey-weighted regression of the outcome on the treatment. For example, if you `mnps()` output object is called `m.out`, you would run:

```
summary(svyglm(Y ~ A, design = svydesign(~1, weights = m.out$weights, data = data)))
```

That will produce treatment effect estimates.

I would urge you to consult a statistician instead of trying to do this analysis yourself. Propensity score analysis with multi-category treatments is a more complicated type of analysis than the ease of the software may make it seem. See my [posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401575/iptw-for-multiple-treatments/401715#401715) about this on CrossValidated for more information.